# Compare 2 sets of data in EXCEL and return what it should be

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, macros, comparison

I need some help with comparing 2 sets of data in Excel (see screenshot below).

[image: Excel Screenshot]

As you can see I have data from 2 sources. Source 1 is the correct data. Source 2 may have been correct at some point but its not up-to-date. I want to be able to look at the Account number and Person in Data Source 2 to see if it matches the Account Number and Person in Data Source 1.

- If it matches then I would like the cell adjacent in column I to remain blank.
- If it DOES NOT match then I would like to bring the person from Data Source 1 into the cell adjacent in column I

**FYI**

- The data starts from row 7 and there could be as many as 5000 Account Numbers
- If the Account Number in source 2 is not in the list of account numbers in Source 1, then I would like the word CHECK to be inserted into the cell adjacent in column I.
- I use Excel 2013

Please find a link to a copy of the spreadsheet below (hosted on Google Drive):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0FUMX_fxi4GelBxS0cxTE00eHM/view?usp=sharing

I tried using 'COUNTIFS' which works to a certain extent; it compares whether they match or not but I can't figure out how to do all of the above that I need. I presume a Macro is needed but I have no clue where to start with creating a Macro to do the above.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vlookup, $B$7:$C$500 is the range in source1, Account Number and Person, with absolute reference to remain fix when you drag the formula down the column, 2 is the 2nd column (Person) to compare with the Person in source2, False to have exact match, write the following in I7 and drag it down:

**=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(F7,$B$7:$C$500,2,FALSE)),"Check",IF(VLOOKUP(F7,$B$7:$C$500,2,FALSE)=G7,"",VLOOKUP(F7,$B$7:$C$500,2,FALSE)))**

On error the formula will write Check in Column I it means the Account Number in F does not exist in source1, if it exists and the corresponding Person is the same in source1 and source 2 it will return blank "", else it will return the correct person in source1.